# How to add md5 password into Spring Security LDAP

Tags: java, spring, security, md5

I am developing a spring ldap authentication and I have problem with md5 and similars I use java configuration for this and I don't know how to encode password.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {  
 auth
 .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain,
            server, dn);
    CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper ldapUserDetailsMapper = new CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper();
    ldapUserDetailsMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(ldapUserDetailsMapper);
    return provider;
}
```

Could anyone help to me?

Comment: Don't use MD5 for passwords. Use BCrypt or SCrypt or PBKDF2

Comment: Yes , I know this.